# The naming of benzene

Tags: nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

Why is **benzene** not called as a **cyclo triene**? Wikipedia says *benzene* is a IUPAC name, but isn't it a common name?

Comment: Benzene is not a triene, the bonds are delocalized.

Comment: @ron I think that entirely exceeds the scope of the question. (Also note that the cyclopentadienyl anion is generally called that, although the bonds and charge are also delocalised.)

Comment: @Jan Well, just my opinion, nothing more. Note that derivatives of 1,3,5-cyclohexatriene have been prepared; their properties are noticeably different from those of benzene.

Comment: @ron I would love to see relevant papers, could you poke me towards them?

Comment: @Jan  See Peter Vollhardt's work on the synthesis and characterization of 1,3,5-triscyclopropabenzene and 1,3,5-triscyclobutabenzene.

Comment: how about phenyl hydride?

Comment: @LiamH Phenyl is a neutral entity, hydride is the hydrogen anion, making phenyl hydride $\ce{[C6H6]-}$. Hydrogen phenyl might do the trick though.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene *does not exist*.

It is just a hypothetically possible structure for the formula $\ce{C6H6}$.

The whole discussion is intended to explain that if it were to exist it would have such and such properties *but it does not exist*.

Instead we have benzene.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a brief explanation of why it doesn't exist. At the moment this seems a bit unsatisfactory as an answer.

Comment: Not to say that this answer is probably a mile away from what the question is *actually* asking.

Comment: \[citation needed\] Ron’s evidence seem to show that derivates of cyclohexatriene exist.

Answer (score 12):

It would be wrong to say *cyclotriene*, rather *cyclo**hexa**triene* would be an appropriate name. And it would also be a highly systematic IUPAC name for said compound, following the rules of e.g. the cyclopentadienyl anion, the cycloheptatrienyl cation, cyclooctatetrene and more.<sup>‡</sup>

Let’s look at benzene’s history. It was discovered as early as 1825 by Michael Faraday who called it *bicarburet of hydrogen*. In 1833, Eilhard Mitscherlich isolated it and named it *benzin*. In 1836 it was isolated by Auguste Laurent who called it *phène*. The name *benzene* also dates back to the first half of the 19<sup>th</sup> century and, like *benzin*, derives from the gum benzoin. Note that this already predates the founding of IUPAC by about 80 years. The first IUPAC nomenclature was not established until 1921.

At the time when it was discovered, chemists had no clue as to what structure it had. It wasn’t until 1865 when Friedrich Kekulé published his ground-breaking paper<sup>[1]</sup> on the structure of benzene which in the end turned out to be correct (-ish). At that time, nomenclature of chemicals was still the Wild West, since there was hardly any way for structure elucidation and thus most chemicals acquired trivial names — some of which survive up to date (acetic acid being a prime example).

When IUPAC finally derived *comprehensive* nomenclatures for organic (and inorganic) compounds, and when structure elucidation was *finally* good enough to prove structures, the names *benzene, benzin* and possibly also *phène* had been in use for many decades, much like many other trivial names. Had IUPAC decided to obsolete them all altogether, they could have just as well trashed their own recommendations, because nobody would have followed them — even today, many chemists are too traditional to take up newer nomenclature schemes even if they have been around for two decades.

Probably to help gain acceptance, IUPAC has always allowed a certain set of retained names to persist under official nomenclature. While the list has gotten smaller over the years, it is extremely unlikely that *benzene, phenol, phenyl* etc. will ever get removed from it, since calling those compounds that way is so prevalent — and short.

Similar things happened to carboxylic acid. Hardly anybody says *methanoic acid* or *butanoic diacid* in place of *formic acid* and *succinic acid*. And sometimes, trivial names even become part of the official nomenclature, as was the case with *fullerene* because it provided a much shorter way to label a certain class of compounds.

So the **short answer** to your question: IUPAC has retained a common name. The reasons are tradition, prevalence and simplicity.

---

**Note:**

‡: Yes, as a chemist I *know* that the structure of benzene is incorrectly represented by drawing three pure double bonds and three pure single bonds, that in reality the molecule has a very high $D_\mathrm{6h}$ symmetry rendering all bonds equal and the electrons in the π system are delocalised all across the molecule. However, that is not what the question is asking about, and not something IUPAC nomenclature cares about.

**Reference:**

[1]: F. A. Kekulé *Bull. Soc. Chim. Paris* **1865**, *3*, 98.

Comment: I disagree, cyclohexatriene is an incorrect name for benzene.  As I mentioned in my comments under the OP's question, derivatives of 1,3,5 cyclohexatriene have been prepared and characterized by Vollhardt's team.  These 1,3,5-cyclohexatrienes behave quite differently from benzene - the names benzene and cyclohexatriene describe different compounds.

Comment: @ron In this and in many other cases concerning nomenclature, IUPAC looks at the compound to be named in an entirely theoretic manner and decides solely by theoretic considerations what to call it. IUPAC’s aim in nomenclature is to be able to take a compound of which you only know a skeletal formula and turn it into a name. Therefore, IUPAC nomenclature would never distinguish between a resonance-stabilised an a non-resonating cyclohexatriene.

Comment: Sounds like a serious shortcoming to me, as 3 double bonds do not exist in benzene.  Since the properties of 1,3,5-cyclohexatriene and benzene differ, it just seems wrong to me to call them both by the same name - but understand, that's just my opinion.

Comment: I second @ron's concern, but following that logic we would have to give the cyclopentadienyl-anion a new name too, because there are certainly no localised double bonds in there, as well as no localised negative charge. In that regard I support the decision to ignore delocalised systems completely and name such species according to it's resonance structures.

Comment: great, I was always wondering about *phenyl* etymology

Comment: @ron When I type "Peter Vollhardt synthesis and characterization of 1,3,5-trichloro benzene" in Google Scholar, I get [zero relevant results](https://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Peter+Vollhardt+synthesis+and+characterization+of+1%2C3%2C5-trichloro+benzene&btnG=). Is it possible that the PDF has been moved or is it behind a non-indexed paywall?

Comment: @GaurangTandon It is not trichloro, see these two papers and references therein; [ref_1](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/anie.199403131), [ref_2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00271a080)

Comment: @ron If you disagree with Jan's answer, could you please post a new answer of your own? Thanks!